# Unable to set an interrupt affinity in linux?

Tags: linux, interrupt

I use ARM processing. I use the `echo` command to set the core of the interrupt number 182, but I will report an error. What is going on?

This interrupt exists, and my processor is 4 cores.

```auto
    117:       4691          0          0          0       GIC  1c50000.eth
    120:          0          0          0          0       GIC  twi3
    121:          0          0          0          0       GIC  twi4
    125:          0          0          0          0       GIC  DE-Interlace
    128:          0          0          0          0       GIC  1000000.tr
    129:          0          0          0          0       GIC  1c31000.tvd0
    130:          0          0          0          0       GIC  1c32000.tvd1
    131:          0          0          0          0       GIC  1c33000.tvd2
    132:          0          0          0          0       GIC  1c34000.tvd3
    182:      26137      27659       7118       2378         -  spiio_irq
    IPI0:          0          0          0          0  CPU wakeup interrupts
    IPI1:          0        757       3544       7480  Timer broadcast interrupts
    IPI2:      45800     159900      99681      68379  Rescheduling interrupts
    IPI3:          7         11          6          6  Function call interrupts
    IPI4:          1          0          0          0  Single function call interrupts
    IPI5:          0          0          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
    IPI6:          0          0          0          0  completion interrupts
    IPI7:          0          0          0          0  CPU backtrace
    Err:          0
    # echo "3" > /proc/irq/182/smp_affinity
    -sh: echo: write error: Input/output error
```